# Sbt Parser fails with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: parsing, sbt

I have an sbt plugin that contains something a Parser similar to this:

```
package sbtpin

import sbt.complete._
import DefaultParsers._

object InputParser {
  private lazy val dotParser: Parser[Char] = '.'
  private lazy val objectId = identifier(Letter, IDChar | dotParser)

  private lazy val addCommand1 = "add" ~> Space.+ ~> objectId ~ (Space.+ ~> NotSpace.+).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))
  private lazy val addCommand2 = "add -n" ~> Space.+ ~> objectId ~ (Space.+ ~> NotSpace.+).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))
  private lazy val addCommand2 = "add -l" ~> Space.+ ~> objectId ~ (Space.+ ~> NotSpace.+).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))

  lazy val parser: Parser[Command] = Space.* ~> (addCommand1 | addCommand2 | addCommand3)
}
```

When trying to run tests with this parser, it fails with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

```
   at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.scala:46)
   at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.scala:51)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:105)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:105)
   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:290)
   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:105)
   at sbt.complete.ParserMain$$anon$3$$anonfun$string$1.apply(Parser.scala:313)
   at sbt.complete.ParserMain$$anon$3$$anonfun$string$1.apply(Parser.scala:313)
   at sbt.complete.Parser$Value.map(Parser.scala:161)
   at sbt.complete.MapParser.resultEmpty$lzycompute(Parser.scala:704)
   at sbt.complete.MapParser.resultEmpty(Parser.scala:704)
   at sbt.complete.Repeat.derive(Parser.scala:834)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
   at sbt.complete.HomParser.derive(Parser.scala:632)
```

Compiling also takes a long time, which is unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was using Space.+, Space.* etc., when Space, OptSpace etc. would be sufficient. This is because Space and OptSpace (which are defined in DefaultParsers) already match multiple characters.

I changed the code to the following, which works fine:

```
package sbtpin

import sbt.complete._
import DefaultParsers._

object InputParser {
  private lazy val dotParser: Parser[Char] = '.'
  private lazy val objectId = identifier(Letter, IDChar | dotParser)

  private lazy val addCommand1 = "add" ~> Space ~> objectId ~ (Space ~> NotSpace).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))
  private lazy val addCommand2 = "add -n" ~> Space ~> objectId ~ (Space.+ ~> NotSpace).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))
  private lazy val addCommand2 = "add -l" ~> Space ~> objectId ~ (Space ~> NotSpace).? map(p => AddCommand1(p._1, p._2))

  lazy val parser: Parser[Command] = OptSpace ~> (addCommand1 | addCommand2 | addCommand3)
}
```

This is how Space, OptSpace, etc. are defined in sbt:

```
/** Matches a single character that is not a whitespace character. */
lazy val NotSpaceClass = charClass(!_.isWhitespace, "non-whitespace character")

/** Matches a single whitespace character, as determined by Char.isWhitespace.*/
lazy val SpaceClass = charClass(_.isWhitespace, "whitespace character")

/** Matches a non-empty String consisting of non-whitespace characters. */
lazy val NotSpace = NotSpaceClass.+.string

/** Matches a possibly empty String consisting of non-whitespace characters. */
lazy val OptNotSpace = NotSpaceClass.*.string

/** Matches a non-empty String consisting of whitespace characters.
* The suggested tab completion is a single, constant space character.*/
lazy val Space = SpaceClass.+.examples(" ")

/** Matches a possibly empty String consisting of whitespace characters.
* The suggested tab completion is a single, constant space character.*/
lazy val OptSpace = SpaceClass.*.examples(" ")
```